# Finding uncertainties of a measured quantity when the distribution of the measured data points is not symmetric

Tags: variance, data-visualization, standard-deviation, measurement-error

If I have a set of data points and they do not take up the form of a symmetric distribution when i plot them as a histogram. Then, can I calculate the mean and standard deviation from their usual formulae? Can I take the standard deviation so calculated to be the uncertainty of that measured quantity even though the spread on one side of the distribution is visibly greater than the other side? Is there any other way to calculate the uncertainty such that I will get different error values on both sides of the mean?

Comment: look at alternatives s.t. the bootstrap

Comment: can you please elaborate